# Is Tensorflow/Docker Useful for Development, or just demo/tests?

Tags: docker, tensorflow

I have been developing in Tensorflow/Python on OSX. Trying to graduate to the big leagues. Bought a big new GPU PC, installed linux, CUDA, Docker, Tensrflow. (Pulled out lots of hair in the process). I thought that Docker-Tensorflow would provide a linux VM environment with Tensorflow, in which I could run my IDE and work from the cmd line like before, but it just seems to serve Jupyter notebooks. I've found some posts with what seem like heroic measures to develop in Docker. I suspect that Docker-Tensorflow is just meant for running demos, serving Jupyter notebooks, etc., and that for development I should revert to a conventional Tensorflow installation. Can someone please confirm (or deny) this? Thanks!

Comment: I just came down the same road, installed tensorflow via docker, don't even know what is a jupyter notebook until the installation is finished, was horrified when realise I have to access through a web interface

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I share your opinion. Instead I use [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) (prior [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv) and [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv)) to maintain environments and (local) dependencies. In detail tensorflow itself has just a few [dependencies](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/setup.py#L34-L39).